# Portable alternative for packed structures with a flexible array member

Tags: c++, gcc, flexible-array-member, packed

Suppose we were writing a C++ network application using UDP sockets. We needed to pass a not-so-small pack of data, so we used this kind of structure, making sure the byte order is the network one:

```
struct [[gnu::packed]] datagram {
    uint64_t timestamp;
    uint8_t type;
    uint32_t temperatures[60]; // whatever, just an example
    uint8_t raw_data[];
};
```

We were using GNU GCC, so we took advantage of non-standard C++ features such as

- flexible array member
- packed structure

We needed a packed structure since we don't want padding in between, as this may be architecture-dependent, and our network program may run on different architectures.

Then, after a year, it may come out that we need to support a non-GCC compiler, which doesn't support those.

Is it possible to do this in standard C++?

Of course, I know we could simply use a `uint8_t buffer[SOME_SIZE]` and memcpy every part of the datagram, but this sounds like a great way to create horrible, really ugly code.

Comment: Find and use a serialization library. This problem has been solved many times, yet people insist on doing it over and over because none of the solutions are good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[gnu::packed]]` is a terrible way to do serialization between arbitrary architectures.  There are still big-endian machines out there.

The right way to do this is to define a serialization format in terms of octets, and then convert between an octet stream (to or from the UDP socket), and a nicely arranged structure.

There are many libraries which make this straightforward.  We use `protobuf` at work; a previous employer had a home-brewed solution.  (Note that a request for a recommendation for such a library is explicit off-topic for Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Sure, so you can keep the data in the structure in network byte order. Edited the OP.